# Not able to access global version of vaiable in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse

I read that using scope resolution operator allows to access the global version of the variable which is local in the current block.

I tried using `::` to access the global version of `n1` but I get error

> symbol 'n1' could not be resolved".

I am using eclipse kepler with CDT added on it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n1=100;
    {
        int n1=200;
        cout<<"n1= "<<n1;
        cout<<"::n1="<<::n1;
    }
    cout<<"n1= "<<n1<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this variable simply isn't defined globally, or do you see it anywhere?

Comment: sorry guys just misunderstood the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::` could be used to access it if it were in the global namespace, outside any function.

But it's not global; it's scoped inside the `main` function body. There is no way to access it if it's hidden by something with the same name in a narrower scope. The only solution is to choose a different name for one of the variables.